# In Ubuntu 14.04 wi-fi is disconnecting when i am not using

Tags: 14.04

when i am stop using the wi-fi connection. wi-fi is automatically disconnecting
how to disable this.

verion:Linux 3.19.0-42-generic #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 18 10:24:49 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ifconfig  results:
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7731 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7731 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:730184 (730.1 KB)  TX bytes:730184 (730.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:00:00:00:00:00
          inet addr:192.168.2.42  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:97190 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:89975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:98994019 (98.9 MB)  TX bytes:12565626 (12.5 MB)

Comment: Please edit questions with output of 'ifconfig'

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right it's likely because the power management shuts down your WiFi interface. Try the following before it gets disconnected:

In a terminal window, enter the following command to disable power management for wlan0:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

If it helps (and only if it helps) you can make this setting permanent as follows:

1. With your favorite editor create and edit /etc/pm/power.d/wifi_pwr_off

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wifi_pwr_off
   ```
2. Add the following two lines on top of the empty file and save it

   ```
    #!/bin/sh 
    /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
   ```
3. Make the created file executable

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/power.d/wifi_pwr_off
   ```
4. Restart your computer

For more detailed information about iwconfig and power management you can use the man pages:

```
man iwconfig
```

... and scroll down to the explanation of the power parameter.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This has probably been answered somewhere else but it was the only simple solution that helped me to fix a WLAN issue. As it does no harm it's the first thing to try. You can always delete the created file afterwards to make things acting like before.